# Modern axiomatically rigorous version of Euclid's Elements

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, math-history

I have been wanting to read Euclid's Elements (Oliver Byrne's version) for a few months, but I have recently learned that a number of the proofs in Euclids Elements are not very rigorous, and that the axioms used by Euclid have been replaced by more rigorous ones. Can anyone suggest a comprehensive resource (ideally a textbook) that rederives Euclid's propositions with a more modern axiomatic approach?

Comment: [Hilbert](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Geometry-Revised-David-Hilbert/dp/B0939ZGBYS/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3M7X34W7Q607R&keywords=david+hilbert+foundations+of+geometry&qid=1652088748&sprefix=hilbert+foundations%2Caps%2C60&sr=8-1) is a standard reference.  [Hartshorne](https://smile.amazon.com/Geometry-Euclid-Beyond-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986502/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1OBB99CJE43OW&keywords=hartshorne+geometry&qid=1652088793&sprefix=hartshorne%2Caps%2C58&sr=8-1) might be more approachable.

Comment: But I strongly suggest starting with Euclid.  Gaps and all.  There's nothing like it.

Comment: Hilbert has covered this topic, indeed. You may take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms, or read Hilbert's book Grundlagen der Geometrie (also mentioned in the wikipedia page).

Comment: Thanks for the references! I've skimmed over Hartshorne actually. Does he effectively sweep through Euclid's Elements and 'fill in the gaps' so-to-speak? And therefore, is it supposed to be read alongside Elements?

Comment: No.  Hartshorne follows Hilbert but in a more student friendly manner.  He also addresses "alternate" geometries in which some critical axioms are weakened or dropped (which I don't recall Hilbert doing, though it's been a while).

Comment: Okay, so I take it that all of Euclid's propositions are not actually re-derived in Hartshorne?

Comment: The problem is Euclid made more assumptions than he noticed. See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms) for an idea of how many.

Comment: Oh, right. I see. Which is to say that many of the propositions in Elements cannot actually be derived from the original axioms? If not, can they be rigorously derived from Hilbert's axioms, for example?

Comment: A lot of propositions, such as the fact that $SAS$ determines a triangle up to congruence are made into axioms, for instance.

Comment: @lulu Ahh, I see. So I guess my question then is - can I obtain as comprehensive a foundation of Euclidean geometry by reading Hartshorne (for example) as opposed to reading Elements (with gaps and all)? Are there additional resources that you could recommend?

Comment: I can't imagine not reading Euclid.  Worth reading Hilbert afterwards to see how the nuts and bolts fit together.  But Euclid first.  Just my opinion, obviously.

Comment: @lulu Awesome, thanks a lot for your advice :)

Comment: The link I provided is to an English version.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! I realised that after I asked, and then deleted my comment haha

Comment: Prenowitz and Jordan, Basic Concepts of Geometry. 
Logical deficiencies in Euclidean geometry, Euclid's parallel postulate, Neutral geometry, Introduction to non-Euclidean geometry, The logical consistency of the non-Euclidean geometries, The empirical validity of the non-Euclidean geometries, Theory of incidence, Incidence geometries: models of the theory of incidence, Theory of affine geometries, Theory of order on the line, Planar and spatial order properties, Angles and order of rays, Separation properties of angles and triangles, (ctd)

Comment: (continued) Theory of congruence: introduction to Euclidean geometry, Congruence without numbers: an introduction

Comment: Have you had a look at Prenowitz & Jordan, niran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't listen to the critics of Euclid. If you are a beginner, start with Euclid's Elements by Sir Thomas L. Heath (Dover, 3 Volumes paperback). You can also read, online the (1996?) posting by David E. Joyce. Once you are finished with Euclid, the you can read Hilbert's, "The Foundations of Geometry." For 2322 years Euclid was recognized as great, so you don't need to worry about his blemishes, until you know him very well.

PS: I have since re-read Robin Hartshorne on Euclid (cited above). Unfortunate this excellent mathematician launches quickly into Hilbert, and does not directly fill in the gaps in Euclid. So reading Hartshorne's Euclid is like reading a simplified version of Hilbert (1899) lectures. As far as I know, no one took Euclid's Elements and simply fill in the gaps, so to speak. However, there was a time in England, in the 19th century when Euclid was published along with Euclid's Data (another extant work of Euclid). I find this work very helpful in understanding or interpreting Euclid's Elements in modern terms. Here is one text online (at the Internet Archive) which includes both: https://ia800201.us.archive.org/17/items/elementseuclida00euclgoog/elementseuclida00euclgoog.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In 1932 George D. Birkhoff published "Set of Postulates for Plane Geometry, Based on Scale and Protractor" which is available online here: http://ckraju.net/geometry/1932_Birkhoff.pdf